# How to check if a file contains a specific set of characters (ex: ^&^)

Tags: text-processing

I have a file which is delimited with `^&^`. Here is a snippet from the file.

```
XML_DOC^&^NUM^&^GEO_REF_ID^&^GRL
```

I need to perform some operations based on the delimiter. How can I check if the file has `^&^` ?
I have tried the below code but that did not work.

```
if grep -q "^&^" "local/filename.txt"; then
        echo "has"
else
        echo "has not "
fi
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -q '\^&^' filename.txt
```

`^` in first position in `grep` means «start of the string».